# Android Studio is not Starting

Tags: android-studio

I have recently installed latest version of Android Studio for Windows 7 32 bit. But after setting up the environment for it installing java jdk and also setting the path variable also all of a sudden it is not starting i am clicking clicking and clicking but the windows does not appear

When i try to debug that through cmd when i try to run studio.bat it says initial size of heap is set to larger than available.

studio.exe.vmoptions file

[image: studio.exe.vmoptions file]

Comment: What's your RAM size?

Comment: buddy i was running android studio two days back all was good but recently i made changes in studio.exe.vmoptions file this caused some error and it is not starting my ram is 4gb it was running smoothly

Comment: can you tell me where is gradle.properties file in android

Comment: It's mostly in ~/.gradle

Comment: it is not there i checked it can i create my new file and edit some properties

Comment: that is heap size of the gradle

Comment: Yeah you can, and if it doesn't work, the best option is to reinstall, that'll reset all the settings

Comment: Instead of taking a picture of a text editor, just paste the contents of the file to your question (and format as code)